# How to execute an interactive scheduled task when the user is not logged in on a Windows Server 2016 VM

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, windows-server-2016, task-scheduler

So I'm trying to execute a powershell program that will open the browser with some website and take screenshot of that webpage and store it somewhere. Its working when I'm logged into the VM. But as soon as I logout or minimize my RDM it still executes but the browser doesn't open and it stores a blank (white) screenshot.

The "Run whether user is logged on or not" option also does not work. Is there any fix for this or any workaround will also do.

Basically I want to take screenshot of this website even though I'm not logged in but that VM is always running.

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT Okay, so the screen shot is necessary because there is some content on that webpage (for example, a notifications page) of which I take a screenshot and then send it via email every morning. Everything works fine when no one is logged in expect it sends a white screen shot.

Comment: Okay so if you run this with PowerShell against your site and to a valid file location on your system, and then open the file, does the opened file contain what you are after as well: `Invoke-WebRequest "https://SomeWebpage.com" -OutFile "C:\Folder\file.html" -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content`. If so, you should be able to embed that into the body of an HTML formatted email or just send that as the attachment in the email. You could also further parse the HTML to potentially only get the portion of the HTML/notification on the site which is of concern with the process.

Comment: Hey, this is so smart workaround I will try this and let you know. I don't want to send it as an attachment. I will try to send it as an html formated email. Thank you.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing the code for your final solution. Consider adding it as a self answer here on your question post and then comment me back to let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PowerShell issue/feature or fix. This is an OS-specific operational boundary.
It is the MS GINA (in legacy WinXP, Win7, Vista), and Explorer user process that allows GUI applications to execute as desinged.

Simply put, this cannot be done. 'Interactive', specifically means, I must be logged on.
In recent versions of Windows, GINA was replaced with credential providers, which are not queried when the user logs out.

Thus, any GUI running on a system must be run in a user context/loaded OS profile (including any needed permissions) for it to render and be accessible.

Comment: OKay. So, is there any workaround for this? Like can this be done in background without requiring for user to login? Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Again, Interactive, this is an OS operational/security restriction. If this was non-interactive, then, you can run code on a non-logged on / locked system via a scheduled task

Comment: After my workout, the only other option that came to mind was,  you have is to set a policy on the remote host via PSRemoting, to allow for automatic logon, think like an OS Kiosk mode, using a defined account, then run your script, then change the setting back and restart the target. Again, IE/MSEdge, etc., browsers only live in a user context. Every time a new user logs on, they must start a browser at least once, before it can be used later in an automation process because the initial browser launch has setup stuff that must happen first.